# Rolling calendar pivot in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, pivot

I have managed to build myself a nice little T-SQL statement that pivots scheduling information into monthly columns.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    t1.customer_code,
    t1.part_number,
    LEFT(DATENAME(month, [formatted_date]),3) as [Month],
    t1.quantity as [quantity] FROM FORECAST_VIEW as t1

    where
        quantity <> 0 
        and formatted_date >= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)  

) as p
pivot
(
    sum(quantity)
    for [Month] in (Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec)
) as p
order by customer_code, part_number
```

This produces an output with the columns

```
customer_code, part_number, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec
```

and sums the required part_number quantities in each month.

This works fine and works wonders in a report however if I could get the month columns to start from the current month and go in order for 12 months, then that would be the icing on the cake.

Problem is that I don't know how to do it.

If I ran it today the output would be

```
customer_code, part_number, Nov, Dec, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct
```

Does anyone have any tips?

Thanks

EDIT
Something I just thought of that I won't rule out if I cannot find a solution but its ugly.
I could put the whole T-SQL statement inside an IF block

```
IF LEFT(DATENAME(month, GETDATE()),3) = 'Nov'
BEGIN
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    ...
) as p
pivot
(   sum(quantity)
    for [Month] in (Nov, Dec, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct)
) as p
order by customer_code, part_number
END
```

and do that 12 times and adjust the pivot months.

Comment: You can pivot into datediff(m..) columns (m0 .. m11) and at client side make column headers dynamic (and fill with correct month names). Or, if you require SQL result with correct column names, then you have to execute dynamic SQL (in stored procedure).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to use dynamic SQL in order to achieve this.

First you must get the month name in the correct order:

```
Declare @cols nvarchar(max);

with list as (
    Select n, m = Left(DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, n, getdate())), 3)
    From (values (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11)) as x(n)
)
Select @cols = STUFF((
        Select ', ' + QUOTENAME(m) 
        From list 
        Order By n
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
,1,1,'');
```

@cols value will be: `[Nov], [Dec], [Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May], [Jun], [Jul], [Aug], [Sep], [Oct]`

Then you can mix your query with @cols and execute it:

```
Declare @sql nvarchar(max);

Set @sql = '
    SELECT *
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
        t1.customer_code,
        t1.part_number,
        LEFT(DATENAME(month, [formatted_date]),3) as [Month],
        t1.quantity as [quantity] FROM FORECAST_VIEW as t1   
        where
            quantity <> 0 
            and formatted_date >= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)  
    ) as p
    pivot
    (   sum(quantity)
        for [Month] in ('+@cols+')
    ) as p
    order by customer_code, part_number;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

If you don't really need dynamic column names and can deal with it in your code with column names such as `[0], [1], ... , [11]` for 12 month ago, 11 month ago, ... up until the previous month, then you can use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    t1.customer_code,
    t1.part_number,
    (12 - DATEPART(month, x) + DATEPART(month, getdate())) % 12 as [Month],
    t1.quantity as [quantity] FROM FORECAST_VIEW as t1

    where
        quantity <> 0 
        and formatted_date >= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)      
) as p
pivot
(
    sum(quantity)
    for [Month] in ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11])
) as p
order by customer_code, part_number
```

`(12 - DATEPART(month, x) + DATEPART(month, getdate())) % 12` will return values such as:

```
Date                    | Month
2015-11-23 16:11:57.860 | 0
2015-10-23 16:11:57.860 | 1
2015-09-23 16:11:57.860 | 2
2015-08-23 16:11:57.860 | 3
2015-07-23 16:11:57.860 | 4
2015-06-23 16:11:57.860 | 5
2015-05-23 16:11:57.860 | 6
2015-04-23 16:11:57.860 | 7
2015-03-23 16:11:57.860 | 8
2015-02-23 16:11:57.860 | 9
2015-01-23 16:11:57.860 | 10
2014-12-23 16:11:57.860 | 11
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for.

What you are basically doing is taking the current date, and adding 0, then 1, then 2 etc to get the rest of the months. 

I thought it should be done like this but I didn't know the syntax to work it out

Comment: Yes it is. It is just a little more complex in the 2nd query because 11 is 12 month ago and so on. This is the reason why I use Modulo (%). In the first, I just remove X month from getdate and get all 12 months.